# Convert RDD of Lists to Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I am trying to convert an `RDD` of lists to a `Dataframe` in Spark.

```
RDD:

['ABC', 'AA', 'SSS', 'color-0-value', 'AAAAA_VVVV0-value_1', '1', 'WARNING', 'No test data for negative population! Re-using negative population for non-backtest.']
['ABC', 'SS', 'AA', 'color-0-SS', 'GG0-value_1', '1', 'Temp', 'After, date differences are outside tolerance (10 days) 95.1% of the time']
```

This is the content of the `RDD`, multiple lists.

How to convert this to a dataframe? Currently, it is converting it into a single column, but i need multiple columns.

```
Dataframe
+--------------+
|            _1|
+--------------+
|['ABC', 'AA...|
|['ABC', 'SS...|
```

Comment: Can you show some more information of your RDD type and the head of the RDD by printing `rdd.take(4)`? You may need to parse your data before converting?

Comment: Example List in an RDD['ABC','AA','1','2','This is a ,test model']

Comment: I want something like this 
column1  column2     column3               column4
AA               1                  2               This is a ,test model

Comment: You need to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order for others to provide an answer that can actually solve your problem.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `Row.fromSeq`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

rdd.map(x => Row.fromSeq(x)).toDF
```